# Azure site assembly dependency error - Works locally

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, azure, web-publishing

I have an MVC website which runs perfectly locally but when I publish to Azure I get the error:

`Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework.SqlServer' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.`

once I navigate to the log in page of the site.

Since the last successful publish I have updated a few NuGet packages, so I think maybe the version of EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll is wrong on the server, but surely it should have been updated during the publish?

I've included assembly binding for the dll:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework.SqlServer" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

How would I check the version of the dll that is present on the server?

JK

Comment: Usually this kind of problem comes in two flavors:
1) You need to set "Copy local" to true for that DLL.
2) You are using an assembly that is also in the GAC, and the versions differ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by FTP'ing into the site and removing the dll, then I removed and readded the dll to my project and republished. I had to do the same for EntityFramework.dll as well.